# Swagger client maps UUI as String

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I am using Jersey and Swagger to expose REST APIs. My resource for the PUT is as below

```
@PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update Employee", response = Employee.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = Responses.MESSAGE_200, response = Employee.class)) })
    public Response updateEmployee(
            @PathParam("id") UUID id,
                @RequestBody String requestBody) throws JsonProcessingException {
}
```

When I generate rest client using Swagger it shows "id" as String even though its data type is UUID.

Can anyone please help me to map  it as UUID?

Comment: Considering java.util.UUID class you are using, If you check toString() method of this class then method's return type is String. So IMO It is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will update the document accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Swagger specification](http://swagger.io/specification/) UUID format isn't supported so it'll be show as string, you can add an example of string that you need on your [`@ApiParam`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations#apiparam) annotation.

```
@PathParam(value='05b2fa78-a0f8-4357-97fe-d18506618c3f', required=true)
```